# OpenGL ES texture rendered not as expected with disproportional aspect ratio triangles

Tags: textures, opengl-es

I cannot seem to understand how texture coordinates work.
I try to render a texture into two triangles and this is what I get

[image]

Where the expected output is a normal continuous image as you can imagine.

Triangles coordinates (where `w = 1080`, `h = 1920`):

```
0, 0, w, 0, 0, h,
w, 0, 0, h, w, h
```

Texture coordinates

```
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

Texture parameters

```
gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: The fact that the moon/planet doesn't look spherical to me seems to suggest that you *might* have perspective correct texturing turned on but haven't set the "W" (and I don't mean your width value) set correctly.

Comment: @SimonF updated the question adding used texture parameters. I tried using `REPEAT` instead of `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` but this hasn't changed the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a piece of paper and draw your 2 triangles vertices coords and uv coords. They seem to be misplaced (e.g. `0,h` corresponds one time to `0,0` and other time to `1,0`)

---

For such cases I could also recommend to use textures with clearly defined characteristics, e.g. a checkerboard with marked uv coords:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me think in a right direction and google the UV picture again. Now I get it. The correct sequence for my scenario is `0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0`.